# As a software tester, how can I test the data in azure data lake?

Tags: azure, testing, bigdata, data-warehouse, azure-data-lake

I would like to validate the data in Azure data Lake that's being ingested by Azure Data Factory.

How can I validate?
What are the different validations that I can do as part of the validation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio enables you to create U-SQL script test cases.

The U-SQL script is compiled and optimized for executable code to run across machines on the cloud or on your local machine. The compilation and optimization process treats the entire U-SQL script as a whole. You can't do a traditional "unit test" for every statement. However, by using the U-SQL test SDK and the local run SDK, you can do script-level tests.

For more details, refer "[Test your Azure Data Lake Analytics code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-cicd-test)".

Hope this helps.